# What is the best way to create a file containing array data to be downloaded and imported later?

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Ok I have an associative array contains data that should be downloaded in a file and then imported later to use the same data later.

it looks like this (only some keys contain arrays):

```
array(
   'id1' => 'Data1',
   'id2' => 'Data2',
   'id3' => 'Data3',
   'id4' => 'Data4',
   'id5' => array(
               'id1' => 'Data1',
               'id2' => 'Data2',
               'id3' => 'Data3'
        )
```

);

so what is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try serialize:

```
file_put_contents($filename, serialize($array));
```

And to read:

```
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Comment: what type of file should I use ? or it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Peter: The filename/extension doesn't matter (usually).

Comment: I myself use example.ser for serialized output, but it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to serialization, you could encode/decode the array with JSON.

[json_encode](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php&ei=4K-eT5qgENHfgge1942WDw&usg=AFQjCNFwbWEXtXdU7euW3Qpv8NQ8zkaLMw&sig2=LVoHmz98KynzXXK_BZsP0g) and [json_decode](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php&ei=96-eT5jwE474ggebn81S&usg=AFQjCNEfzaIfzofmQZOFSYuv9P5S_iMCJA&sig2=-VDNi-_d_SdQtmufDjsKVg)

Answer (score 0):

[Serialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it when you save it and then [unserialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it when you read it back in.